# How to modify background of the menu dropdown container

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui

I changed `colorOnSurface` as specified in the material doc and all properties but this background is still black, how is it possible to modify this element?

[image: screen menu background]

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/parameter_gender_selector"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="21dp"
            android:hint="@string/genre"
            android:textColor="@color/loginButtonColorBackground"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0.7dp"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/loginButtonColorBackground">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/actv_gender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/genre"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@color/grayFont"
                android:textColorHint="@color/loginButtonColorBackground" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: share your code..

Comment: yes sorry, i share it